# Not able to get Google analytics real time data

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I am not able to get Analytics Real time Data. I have added tracking script to header.php file of wordpress, still it is showing 0 active users, even though I have opened the site in two devices.

Answer (score 0):

When did you create the Google Analytics profile?  It can take up to 72 hours to start recording data.

When did you add the JS to your website?  it can take up to 24 hours to be detected.

Comment: Yeah!. I wanted to check real time data. It is showing now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is working now. Some chrome extension was blocking js code. I uninstalled all chrome extensions working fine now.
Thanks :)